# DateTime Parse error for millisecond level

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

How to parse the datetime in millisecond for "20160803T0509+0100". I cannot change the input datetime format as I am receiving by client data file.

Client is using as a system local server time in UTC iso 8601 with offset

I am useing the simple function

```
 Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime("20160803T0509+0100"));
```

Error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Wait a second.. Is your `+0100` part for seconds and milliseconds like `01` as seconds and `00` as milliseconds? Are you _really_ sure it is not [UTC Offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)? I never see that format before. And kind of weird since it has `+` sign before.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `+0100` is for time zone offset not milliseconds

```
var dateTime= DateTime.ParseExact("20160803T0509+0100", "yyyyMMddTHHmmzzz", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead

```
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("20160803T0509+0100", "yyyyMMddTHHmm+ssff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20160803T0509+0100", "yyyyMMddTHHmmzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```